# Divide projects to several DLL files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I've got a small but annoying problem. I've got C# project in VS 2010 with structure like this:

```
DL.cs
PL.cs
BO.cs
Main.cs
```

I need to convert the files DL.cs, PL.cs, BO.cs to the dlls.
I tried to create another Class Library project and add that project and then copy one file to Class Library project, but every time I do it, it reminds me that I need to add reference to previous project. How can I do it? I suppose I need to add assembly informations but I'm newbie and I have no idea where or how...

Thx for help and sorry for my english

Comment: Right click the references node in each project. There is add in there.

Comment: But references are DLL, EXE etc. but i need reference to another project or file.

Comment: you can't reference files - in that dialog there is a project tab - it shows the other projects in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Add a Project Reference to a Visual Studio Web Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Right click the References item under your project and select Add Reference. Expand the solutions tab on the left hand side and click on the Project tab. Select (tick) the project you would like to reference and click Ok.

Are you sure you want one dll per class, that seems sort of odd?

Comment: Yes, maybe it seems to be stupid but it's only exercise. Every file contains specific data for example DL (data layer) includes only Lists, arrays and other data structures, BO (business objects) are classes with "activities" and main objects of app connects PL (presentation layer) with DL.

So the problem is how can I create DL as dll library when it refers to another file (BO). It looks like this:
In DL: `List<User> UsersList = new List<User>();`
In BO is definition of User class ` public class User`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @DanielA.White Fair point. Link only isn't really an answer, fixed.